# Why do I have to authorize my map-editor every time I open it?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net, drm, galaxy-editor

I begrudgingly understand the lack of LAN and the default to "always-on" battle.net connection required to enjoy the single and multiplayer aspects of Starcraft II.

But why do I have to log in to use the editor? Sometimes the editor lets me 'map-edit' without an outside verification, but every so often (it seems almost randomly, to me) it forces me to "authenticate my account". What is the editor doing that mandates a connection to battle.net? Is this just Blizzard's DRM overextending its hand at my expense?

Is there anything I can do so I don't have to log-in every time I want to test and/or edit my map?

Comment: Is it when you open the map editor, or when you test the map?  I've only had to login when testing the map.

Comment: I don't need to login, neither when opening the editor nor when launching the edited map. I only need to input password (and sometimes username) when launching the game regularly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, with the advent of patch 1.1, I discovered the *real* answer to this question.

> When loading documents with Battle.net-only dependencies, you will now be prompted to log in >and download the dependency data, rather than failing to load.

So the reason you have to log in, as that the default map (or my default map at least) had some online dependencies that I didn't know about.

**Legacy Answer:**

[From the Galaxy Editor FAQ on the Battle.net forums:](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/189279023)

> Do I have to authenticate to use [the editor]?
>
> Yes! You need to authenticate the
>   Editor once every time a new patch is
>   released, other than that, you should
>   not need to authenticate.

So apparently, starcraft 2 is patching a lot more often than I was aware of...

Comment: makes perfect sense.  I play more often than I edit maps, so anytime there has been a patch, i must have played before using the editor.  therefore, i've never been asked to log in for just the editor.

Comment: The previous answer was incorrect. It has now been updated, and should be accurate.

Answer (score 8):

> **12. Duration of the “On-line” Component.** The Game is capable of both offine and online player modes, both of which require that you obtain authorized access to the Service. You understand and agree that the Service is provided by Blizzard at its discretion and may be terminated or otherwise discontinued by Blizzard pursuant to the Terms of Use.
>
> <sub>from the [EULA](http://www.scribd.com/doc/36780086/Star-Craft-2) (skip to page 11)</sub>

You have to authorize your map-editor because you agreed to.

Comment: Heck, not only that, but they can decide to quit letting you play the game--online *or* offline--any time they want.  It's all there in the EULA.  Ultimately it would be up to a court to decide if that sort of thing is really enforceable, but Blizzard has had luck with the courts in the past.

Comment: Right. But half the time, the map editor doesn't make me authorize, half the time it does. What's the criteria for deciding, "oh, you need to validate the map editor *this* time"?

Comment: @Raven, I hope you are not expecting me to answer that question :)

Comment: @Badp, that *was* the intent of asking this question in the first place.

Comment: If it was I (and the four upvoters) must have misread the question, @Raven -- I thought you asked why was the connection needed in the first place. The reason why you don't get always asked for authorization could, for example, be a previous authentication token that has not expired yet. I don't own the game and can't tell for sure.

Comment: @Raven: You should probably edit your question to reflect that it only asks *sometimes*. :)

Comment: @Kyralessa, It's not that it's hard, it's that it's irritating and (from my perspective) pointless.

Comment: -1. While answer is technically correct, it's completely useless to the original poster. Simillar to answering "yes" to a person asking you if you have a watch.

Comment: @Mavrik, if you read the other comments you'll see the original asker wasn't very clear to begin with ;)